# Update mySQL table if row from another table is certain value

Tags: php, mysql

```
UPDATE table1 SET row1 =CONCAT( row1, 'word1, word2')
```

I want to add a condition to the query above.

I'm looking to add text values to row1 on table1, which already contains some texts, the query above does the trick, but additionally to that, I need to add a condition. I have another table called "table2", with a column, let's say "row2" that equals to "1". I need to run the query above IF row2 in table2 equals to 1.

I'm running the query directly on PHP MyAdmin

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS? sqlserver <> mysql. Aside from that your question lacks enough detail to help much.

Comment: When you use the word **`row`** do you infact mean **`column`**?

Comment: Is there anything more you would like to tell us, like which COLUMN(S) are used to **link** Table1 to Table2

Comment: Yes, I meant column, my bad. column "row2" is used to link table1 to table2

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = "SELECT `row2` FROM `table2`";
$res = mysqli_query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
if($row['row2'] == 1)
{
   //run your update table code: UPDATE table1 SET row1 =CONCAT( row1, 'word1, word2')
}
```

Comment: Sorry mike but thats just nonsense. I admit the question is too but even so.

Comment: I'm actually running the query directlt on PHP myAdmin